# Behaviour of cd with an empty string argument

Tags: bash

I have a small command that goes to the root of git repository:

```
cg() {
  cd "$(git rev-parse --show-toplevel)"
}
```

When not within git repository it executes `cd ""` which, I thought, is supposed not to do anything.

However after also setting `$CDPATH` now this behaviour seems to have changed. Instead `cd ""` takes me to `$CDPATH`.

My question: is this a small bug or a documented/expected behaviour?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a probably-unintended consequence of how `cd` and `CDPATH` are specified (and implemented) to behave, together with the fact that a trailing "/" character is allowed on a directory path (e.g. `/tmp/` is (mostly) equivalent to `/tmp`).

According to the [POSIX standard for the `cd` command](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/cd.html):

> Starting with the first pathname in the <colon>-separated pathnames of
>   `CDPATH` (see the ENVIRONMENT VARIABLES section) if the pathname is
>   non-null, test if the concatenation of that pathname, a <slash>
>   character if that pathname did not end with a <slash> character, and
>   the *directory* operand names a directory.

Note that the "if the pathname is non-null" refers to what's in `CDPATH`, not the *directory* argument to the `cd` command, so that's not relevant here.

Consider what happens if the specified *directory* is the empty string. Suppose `CDPATH` is set to "/foo/bar", and that directory exists. If you run `cd ""`, the `cd` builtin will compute "/foo/bar" + "/" + "" = "/foo/bar/" (which is just a more-verbose way of specifying the directory /foo/bar), find that that directory exists, and move to it.

Comment: I think you are correct about how this happens, Thank you for the explanation. I wonder if it is something that should be reported to the bash mailing list. If there are people depending on `cd ""` behaviour, like I foolishly was, then it would be broken by simply setting `$CDPATH` which seems like a totally unrelated thing.

Comment: @KarolisKoncevičius I don't think it can be considered a bug, since it is the result implied by the POSIX specification. And I think `cd ""` isn't really a reasonable command anyway -- If anything, I'd argue that it should generate an error, because the empty string isn't a valid directory name. (Note that passing an empty argument is significantly different from not passing an argument at all, as in plain `cd`).